# C - Why does getopt return 255 on linux?

Tags: c, getopt

I've been fooling around with `getopt` (from unistd.h) recently. I wrote some code that worked fine under Windows 7 compiled with gcc from MinGW, while not working under Raspbian Linux on my Raspberry Pi (I compiled them both with gcc, no options; `gcc t.c`). For some reason getopt returns int 255 or char ÿ when faced with no switches, when really it should return -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char t;
  opterr = 0;

  while ((t = getopt(argc, argv, "a:")) != -1)
    switch (t) {
      case 'a':
        printf("-a with argument %s\n", optarg);
        return 0;
      case '?':
        printf("uknown option\n");
        return 1;
      default:
        /* This is always 255 under linux, and is never reached under windows */
        printf("getopt returned int %d (char %c)\n", t, t);
        return 2;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

One tought I had was that, actually 255 *is* -1 in unsinged 8-bit arithmetic, so I tried to put an int cast in the while conditional, but that did nothing.

Comment: Getopt() returns an int. change `char t;` to `int t;` and you'll be fine. (the -1 will signify EOF, or in this case: no more options. You can handle it by adding `case -1: break;`)

Comment: `getopt` hasn't returned `EOF` since POSIX.2, according to my man page.  It returns -1 when it can't find any more options.

Comment: @CarlNorum I have no idea what you mean, care to elaborate?

Comment: wildplasser mentioned `EOF` and I just wanted to clarify that the actual `EOF` constant from `stdio.h` isn't returned by `getopt`, and hasn't since 1992 or so.

Comment: Well, I think he is refering to EOF as in 'end of file', or rather end of input, not that.

Comment: Exactly. I meant it in an abstract sense, as an EOF *condition*, not as the defined constant from stdio.h. (This is the same return convention as sscanf() uses, even though the input string is not a file)

Comment: But `sscanf` does return the `EOF` constant, doesn't it?  It's just coincidence that `EOF` is `-1` on most systems.  Anyway, that's the clarification I wanted to make - between the semantics of "end-of-file" and the literal use of `EOF` as a constant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like your system/toolchain defaults to an unsigned `char` type.  That means when `getopt()` returns -1, it gets converted to 255 and stored in `t`.  Then that 255 gets promoted to `int` type (staying 255) and compared to `-1`, which can't ever match.

`getopt()` returns `int`, so you should really declare `t` as `int` to match, but if you're set on using `char`, you're going to need to use `signed char`.

Aside: Since you say you're compiling with gcc, you might also find the `-fsigned-char` flag helpful if you want this and other `char` variables in your program to be signed.

Second Aside: You can duplicate the failure by passing the `-funsigned-char` flag or by changing `t` to be an `unsigned char` in your Windows test, if that makes it easier to debug.

Comment: As a minor note, C programs do not require `main()` to have a return statement.

Comment: be fair. it has 3 return statements. it just doesn't have one for when it drops out of the while loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot a return statement, but that's not the actual code I used, I'll edit it though.